# Wait for Redis get to set array in Node.JS

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, redis, socket.io

I'm learning Javascript / Node.JS and it's going well but I ran in some trouble with the code below. When I open the page that emits a hit it outputs the trck_visitors array in Node.JS however. On the first hit this array is empty, it does not show the **trck_visitors[socket.id]** which I just set. If I refresh the page I see in the console.log output the ID from the previous hit but not from the current hit.

Why doesn't it output the **trck_visitors[socket.id]** which I just set but does output the **trck_visitors[socket.id]** from previous hits?

```
var trck_visitors = [];

io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
    socket.on('hit', function (data) {
            redis.get("Node->Username->"+parseInt(getToken), function(err, reply) {
                if(reply === null){
                    trck_visitors[socket.id] = {'Gebruikersnaam' : 'Gast', 'Page' : data.url};
                }else{
                    trck_visitors[socket.id] = {'Gebruikersnaam' : reply, 'Page' : data.url};
                }
            });

        console.log(trck_visitors);
    });
});
```

### Edit:

Updated the code to the actual code. Redis seems to be the problem, console.log does not wait for redis.get to set **trck_visitors[socket.id]**. How can I make the rest of the code wait for redis.get to set **trck_visitors[socket.id]**?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have already identified your problem: `console.log` is being executed before the response from Redis comes. This is a typical situation for asynchronous code.

So, just put your logging into the Redis' callback:

```
var trck_visitors = [];

io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
  socket.on('hit', function (data) {
    redis.get("Node->Username->"+parseInt(getToken), function(err, reply) {
      if(reply === null){
        trck_visitors[socket.id] = {'Gebruikersnaam' : 'Gast', 'Page' : data.url};
      }
      else {
        trck_visitors[socket.id] = {'Gebruikersnaam' : reply, 'Page' : data.url};
      }

      console.log(trck_visitors);
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: Ouch, how stupid of me. Ofcourse thats the way to go. Time for a break I guess because I clearly can't think logically anymore ;)

Comment: :) Yeah, it happens. Take care!